# convert a typeorm Entity into json schema

Tags: reflection, jsonschema, typeorm, fastify

I'm working on a fastify rest server implementation in JS and I want to use the same typeorm entity as the json schema for the rest API which will allow validation and swagger documentation.

An entity example might be:

```js
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
class Location {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id = undefined;

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 100 })
    name = '';

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 255 })
    description = '';
}

export default Location;
```

The route itself:

```js
fastify.get('/', { schema }, async () => (
  // get all Locations from the database
));
```

For the `schema` object (passed as the second argument to fastify route), I need to pass a json schema describing the body and/or return value (in this case, the return value)
The schema should look something like:

```js
{
  schema: {
    response: {
      200: {
        type: 'array',
        items: {
          type: 'object',
          properties: {
            id: { type: 'string', primary: true, generated: true },
            name: { type: 'string', maxLength: 100 },
            description: { type: 'string', maxLength: 255 }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Bottom line, I want to convert the Entity above to this schema.
Is there a method in Typeorm that converts the class into a json structure or do I need to somehow reflect on the class.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the solution was pretty simple - `connection.getMetadata(Location)` gives much information on the table. I just had to convert that data to the json schema that I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and looking around I found a small npm module called [typeorm-schema-to-json-schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typeorm-schema-to-json-schema) created for this purpose, thought it requires [defining entity classes as EntitySchemas](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/separating-entity-definition) instead.